# Function[0], Function[,0], and Function[{},0]: Is there any inherent distinction in the "academic" sense?

Tags: function-construction, core-language, functional-style

Note that `Function[,0]` is by default interpreted as `Function[Null,0]`.
The following three calls all give `0`:

```
Off[Syntax::com]

Construct[Function[0](*a constant pure function*)]
(* 0 *)

Construct[Function[, 0](*a constant pure function*)]
(* 0 *)

Construct[Function[List[], 0](*a constant pure function*)]
(* 0 *)
```

So each of them has the same effect. But internally, do they obey *identical* mechanisms? In other words, are there any **subtle** distinctions?

Comment: The question is more interesting than I thought. `Function[Null, Null][3]` returns `Null`!

Comment: There is a subtle distinction between the last construction and the other two. The first two are functionally equivalent, but I don't know if there are any subtle differences in implementation. In the last construction you are declaring that no arguments will even be inspected as part of evaluating the body. Since these are all effectively constant functions, it's difficult to see the distinction, but if instead of `0` the body were `#` it would be easier to see. In some sense, the last construction is the only true constant function.

Comment: `Function[List[], 0][] // RepeatedTiming` consistently takes longer than the other two for me. The other two are nearly tied, but on average `Function[0]` is slightly faster. It may be nothing more than the difference in evaluating the arguments of `Function[..args..]`.

Comment: @xzczd `Function[Null, ...]` is an undocumented way to define a function that uses `Slot` arguments. It's usually only used when you want to use the 3-arg form with `SlotSequence`. For example `Function[Null, Hold[Plus[##]], HoldAll]`.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Actually, `Function[Null, …]` is not undocumented; it is documented in the "[Details](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html)" of the help page. However, I've never seen anyone use it in *practical* applications (e.g., a production environment).

Comment: @user688486 Oh, I never spotted that line. I've certainly used it in practice myself when I need to hold arguments in pure functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have direct knowledge, but the following is what I infer based on experimentation.

Consider the following:

- Function[##]

  ```
  Function[##][]
  (* Sequence[] *)

  Function[##][] // Trace
  (* {(##1&)[],HoldForm[]} *)
  ```

  So, the `##` captured the argument sequence, which happened to be empty.
- Function[, ##]

  ```
  Function[, ##][]
  (* Sequence[] *)

  Function[, ##][] // Trace
  (* {Function[Null,##1][],HoldForm[]} *)
  ```

  While the intermediate representations are different (or at least displayed differently), this form is functionally identical to the previous. I have no way of knowing whether there are implementation differences at a lower level which are opaque to us, but I suspect that any differences are insignificant to the point of allowing us to conclude that this form is also "mechanistically" identical to the previous.
- Function[{}, ##]

  ```
  Function[{}, ##][]
  (* ##1 *)

  Function[{}, ##][] // Trace
  (* {Function[{},##1][],##1} *)
  ```

  By providing an empty list for the argument spec, we are bypassing the step of trying to do replacements into the body of the function. Further experiments show that any arguments are still evaluated, but the step of replaceing their values into the function body is skipped.

Extending this line of argument to your specific examples, I would conclude the following. In the case of `Function[0][]`, the argument sequence (after the evalutor evaluated it) is consumed by `Function`, then the body is inspected for slots, and then the replacement of the arguments into those slots turns out to be a no-op (or maybe there is logic to short circuit if no slots are found).

In the case of `Function[{}, 0][]`, the argument sequence is ignored altogether by `Function` (although the evaluator probably had a crack at it).

Providing further evidence:

```
Function[{}, ##][a, b] // TracePrint
(*  Function[{},##1][a,b]
     Function[{},##1]
      Function
      a
      b
     ##1 *)

Function[, ##][a, b] // TracePrint
(*  Function[Null,##1][a,b]
     Function[Null,##1]
      Function
      a
      b
     HoldForm[a,b]
      Sequence
      a
      b *)
```

Maybe there are nuances to what `TracePrint` presents to us, but what this suggests to me is that (reiterating what I said above) a `Function` with an explicit empty list skips the replacement step entirely.

**Update**

Inspired by @MichaelE2's comment, I see three main buckets for timings

- Fastest

  `Function[0]`, `Function[Null,0]`

  The number of arguments passed can affect the speed, but that's expected. The body must have no slots to get this speed.
- Middle

  `Function[{}, 0]`, `Function[{}, ##]`

  Presence or absence of slots makes no difference. Again, number of arguments has an effect as expected.
- Slowest

  `Function[##]`, `Function[, ##]`, `Function[{<vars>}, <body>]`

  Same comments apply with one exception: The specific form of `Function[##][arg]` is slightly faster than the middle tier above. It must be the `Function[##]` form, not the `Function[Null, ##]` form and the argument sequence must be a singleton.

My guess is that there is some special casing going on in the implementation. That in turn suggests that my analysis above is incomplete.

Your original question asked only about forms of `Function` applied to empty argument lists, but even the slightest extensions suggest that there are subtleties that distinguish between the form variations of `Function` expressions.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're considering something like `Function[{}, ##]`, which is not really a valid construct if there's no outer Function that encapsulates the slots. Naked slots should always be avoided .

Comment: It's just a test/experiment to try to gain insight. Keep the body constant and change the argument signature. Keep the signature constant and change the body. Etc, etc.